# Open Browser in Background - loading web page in background

Tags: android, url, browser, background, loading

i'am trying to load an url in background using the default browser. So the user can switch to the browser whenever he finished reading the current activity and the page is already loaded.

Is there a way to fire an Intent (Browser) but stay in the original Activity?

I'am aware of the FrameLayout approach with setting the visibilty but this is not possible with the default browser.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to fire an Intent (Browser) but stay in the original Activity?

No, sorry.

Comment: In my case browser open in background in case of only Lg g3 device?

Answer (score 0):

no they say it overloads the ui and takes to long rather use the  Asynctask

```
final class MyNetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Void> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(final Void param) {
  ...
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final URL... args) {
 ...
 return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Void param) {
 ...
}
```

}